# Can I give my user a choice to choose his own subdomain in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I have implemented multi-tenancy in a project with unique subdomains & separate dbs. Now, my client said that we will provide subdomain of customer’s choice. In this way, duplication is obvious. The flow is like this:

If two users have this one domain (user1 => http://user.abc.com & user2 => http://user.abc.com ), then how can I determine who is who? The main problem is, I am going to register the user myself, there is no registration process for the customer, so, customer will provide his domain to us manually for example: he likes to have his domain “user” and if I would have “user” already in my database, how can I provide the same hostname to my another customer. Won’t it seems strange that we are calling our customer back and telling them that we have already this hostname please give us another name of your choice. Yes, all this makes sense when we would have been giving the registration process to our customer and there he can enter hostname of his own choice like we enter our email addresses on gmail, hotmail and etc. Please tell me if I am going in wrong direction.

Here is my code:

routes/web.php

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'subdomain'],  function () {
      Route::get('/sales', 'HomeController@index');

      Route::get('/sales/register', 'HomeController@register');
 });
```

Middleware/SubDomainAccess.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {   
    $server = explode('.', $request->server('HTTP_HOST'));
    $subdomain = $server[0]; 

    $config = array();    

    if($subdomain == "myapp"){
        $defaultSite = SuperAdminModel::where('db_name', 'main_db)->first();

        $config['id'] = $defaultSite["admin_id"];
        $config['site_url'] = $defaultSite["site_url"];  
        $config['host'] = "localhost";
        $config['db_name'] = "main_db";           
        $config['user'] = "my_user";
        $config['password'] = "mypassword";
        $request->attributes->add(['myAttribute' => "SUPER ADMIN"]);   
    }
    else{
        $site = TenantModel::where('tenant_hostname', $subdomain)->first();

        if(!is_null($site)){
            $config['id'] = $site["id"];
            $config['tenant_domain'] = $site["tenant_domain"];
            $config['tenant_hostname'] = $site["tenant_hostname"];
            $config['db_name'] = "mysite_".$site["id"]."_".$site["tenant_hostname"]."_db";
            $config['user'] = "my_user";
            $config['password'] = "mypassword";
            $config['host'] = "localhost";
            $request->attributes->add(['myAttribute' => $site['tenant_company_name']]);
        }else{
           return abort(404);
        }

    } 


    \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $config['host'] );
    \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $config['db_name'] );
    \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $config['user']);
    \Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $config['password']);


    \DB::reconnect();


    return $next($request);
  }
```

If more details are required to understand the code, I will provide it.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure exactly the use case so maybe you can clarify. If the idea is that people will be using each site, then you wouldn't want to have multiple "user.abc.com" because it will be ambiguous to outside users. If however the site is only ever used by a specific logged in user, you could direct traffic to certain controllers/views differently based on the current user even if the domain is the same

Comment: @tam Hmm, but I was implementing the logic like this when user will visit his url (domain), it will be connected to his separate database and then user will logged in to his personal space as each user will have separate database. The information about all my customers and their domains and databases are stored in my main database. When user will visit his domain his database name will be fetched from main database and then he will be connected to his respective database. In this scenario, I thought unique subdomain is important. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve what you want with the same sub domain as I suggested with adding some logic. You say you have an implementation so share that and then maybe we can alter it. However, I do think it's reasonable to tel a client hey that sub domain is taken choose another one

Comment: @tam Yeah, I wish that we can do that but my client don't want that too. I am editing my question with my code. Please have a look. Thanks so much.

Comment: In my project each customer's space and data should be isolated from each other each customer's database will have login credentials for their own company, so data security is very important here.